# How to configure private NPM and Bower registries in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: npm, visual-studio-2015, bower, private-bower

We are using Visual Studio 2015 and also ProGet to host private feeds of NuGet, NPM and Bower. I'm trying to figure out the best way to have all of our team members pointed at our private registries with the least amount of effort. I know for Bower I can set a private repo in the .bowerrc file like so

```
{
  "directory": "wwwroot/lib",
  "registry": "http://proget.mysite.com/bower/Bower",
  "search": "http://proget.mysite.com/bower/Bower"
}
```

and for NPM, I can use the command line to control it like so

```
npm config set registry http://proget/npm/private-npm
```

But I'd like a way to disseminate this to the team as easy as possible with minimal effort on their part and to not have to set it for each solution. It should apply globally.  How can I do this? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the specs: http://bower.io/docs/config/#placement--order you can keep your .bowerrc file in the user's home folder(and some other places) so it would not need to be configured for every project. The best option may be just to keep the file in version control and have your devs pull it and store it locally.

Answer (score 0):

So after a little digging I figured this out.  For npm, just use that command I listed in my question.

- npm config set registry http://proget/npm/private-npm

For bower, the default registry can be changed by swapping out the bower.herokuapp.com url in the following files:

```
    * 
        * C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\node_modules\bower-config\lib\util\defaults.js
        * C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\node_modules\bower-registry-client\test\Client.js
        * C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\test\commands\register.js
```